# Node.js app doesn't load correctly when accessed via localhost:port, but works with docker ip

Tags: angularjs, node.js, sqlite, docker, ssl

I have a webapp running on a docker container whose port 443 is exposed and mapped to port 32770 on local host.

When I access the webapp on my linux host via:
1) https://container-ip : Web app runs fine without any issues.
2) https://localhost:32770 : Web app loads but is unable to communicate with middleware

(Middleware runs on container and maintains an sqlite DB and talks to app via websocket using port 9000)

**Edit1:**
Docker output:

```
fzkl@nemean-lx:~/repo/ams-emulator$ sudo docker ps  
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                 COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                           NAMES  
7ce281d8a66a        atonlabemu_only_443   "./start.sh"        18 minutes ago      Up 18 minutes       0.0.0.0:32771->443/tcp                          sleepy_lamport  
1b6f03255d16        atonlabemu_only_443   "./start.sh"        6 hours ago         Up 6 hours          0.0.0.0:32770->443/tcp                          unruffled_euler
```

I noticed that UI interaction when accessed via localhost:port doesn't register into the app logs.

**Edit2:**

```
# cat serverConfig.json 
{
  # private stuff
  "secondaryMemoryPath":"/media/sdcard",
  "port":{
    "normal":9000,
    "critical":9001,
    "uiHost":443
  }
}
```

On the middleware side, cfg file:

```
[websocket]
normal-communication-port=9000
critical-communication-port=9001
```

Any help on getting the webapp and middleware to communicate while accessing through localhost:port is much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: What is the output of "docker ps"?

Comment: Updated description.

Comment: The port mapping of docker container looks ok. Your problem seems to be in the app itself and how it is connected to the middlewars .. May be useful if you send related snippets of where you configure the connection or any logs?

Comment: Updated node server details and the middleware cfg.

Comment: There is a docker-proxy service running on my host. It looks like this docker-proxy service has issue with socket io communication.